# insert path URL into values an array

Tags: laravel, api

**i want to add the url image in value to array**

```
public function show(){

    $halls = DB::table('halls')
        ->join('imagas','halls.id','=','imagas.id_Halls')
        ->select('halls.id','halls.hall_name','halls.hall_adress','halls.hall_details','price_hours','price_int','halls.hall_name','imagas.image_path')->where('halls.id',157)
        ->get();

$results=[];

foreach ($halls as $hall) {

$array=json_decode($hall->image_path,true);
if (is_array($array))
{
   $hall->image_path = $array;

    }
    array_push($results, $hall);
}

return response()->json($results);

}
```

**output like this**

> {
>           "id": 157,
>           "hall_name": "ali",
>           "hall_adress": "st-50",
>           "hall_details": null,
>           "price_hours": "3000",
>           "price_int": "500",
>           "image_path": [
>               "1579635535.jpg",
>               "1579635536.jpg",
>               "1579635537.png",
>               "1579635538.png"
>           ]
>       }

**but i need pass string path url to array  and show output like this**

> {
>           "id": 157,
>           "hall_name": "ali",
>           "hall_adress": "st-50",
>           "hall_details": null,
>           "price_hours": "3000",
>           "price_int": "500",
>           "image_path": [
>               "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images_ravs/1579635535.jpg",
>               "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images_ravs/1579635536.jpg",
>               "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images_ravs/1579635537.png",
>               "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images_ravs/1579635538.png"
>           ]
>       }

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the image array and add the rest of the URL.

```php
foreach ($halls as $hall) {
    $array = json_decode($hall->image_path, true);

    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach($array as $index => $image) {
            $array[$index] = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images_ravs/" . $image;
        }

        $hall->image_path = $array;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.